# Distributed systems where to send requests?

Tags: distributed, microservices

How do different components in a distributed system know where to send messages to access certain services?

For example, lets say  I have a service which handles authentication, and a service which handles searching. How does the component which handles searching know where to send an authentication request? Are subdomains more commonly used? If so, how does replication work in this scenario? Is there some registry of local IP addresses which handles all this routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing is called service lookup / service registry / resource lookup / .. and it depends. It depends on how large your system is and how dynamic it is.

If you only have few components, it might be feasible enough to store the necessary information in a config file, or pass it as parameter. Generally, many use DNS as a lookup system, but it’s not considered to be a good one, due to the caching and long latency.

I think most distributed systems use [Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) to store this information for them. This way, all the services only need to know the IP-addresses of the Zookeeper cluster. If you have replication, you just store multiple addresses inside Zookeeper, and depending on which system you are using, you’ll need to choose an address on your own, or the driver does it (in case you’re connecting to a replicated database for instance).

Another way to do this, is to use a message queue, like ZMQ which will forward the messages to the correct instances. ZMQ can deal with replications and load balancing as well.

Comment: So how does a service register itself with the registry? Does it just ping the registry upon startup, or does the registry need to be given its address in advance? I realize this may be implementation specific, you can just tell me if "it depends".

Comment: for zookeeper you just include the connection information at a specific key, which all other services will use to find you, ZMQ I'm not sure about - it isn't really correct, but you could see zookeeper as a reliable distributed in-memory database (but only use it for configuration values, don't try using it for actual data)